# Custom switch appearing stretched

Tags: android

I've developed a custom drawable for Switch's thumb and track but the problem is that it's appearing stretched:

[image]

Does anyone have any idea what's causing this?
My  XML's are below:

**Layout.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/switch1"
        android:padding="5dp" />

    <Switch
        android:id="@+id/switch1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:thumb="@drawable/switch_thumb_selector"
        android:track="@drawable/switch_track_selector" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/switchErrorView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/switch1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text=""
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_red_light"
        android:visibility="gone" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**switch_thumb_selector.xml**

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/switch_thumb_inactive" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/switch_thumb_inactive" android:state_checked="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/switch_thumb_inactive"/>

</selector>
```

**switch_track_selector.xml**

```
<item android:drawable="@drawable/switch_track_green" android:state_checked="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/switch_track_white" android:state_checked="false"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/switch_track_white"/>
```

**Green Track Drawable:**

[image]

Comment: Can you attach your `switch_track_green` drawable?

Comment: I've attached the drawable.

Comment: I just realized that my horizontal 9 patch dot is not in the centre of the image. Let me see if correcting that makes a difference.

Comment: Update: It didn't make a difference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think thats bad behavior has appeared because you didn't draw "content" area. Try this drawable, I've tested and it was working for me.
[image: switch_bg.9.png]

Comment: That worked. I didn't know about the content area thing. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @rom4ek Can you explain the content area thing? I have faced the same problem, not sure what did you meant by "didn't draw content area".